# Multiple arguments in toast notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I can send and receive single params using

```xmls
string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                   "<wp:Toast>" +
                        "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                        "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                        "<wp:Param>/Evento.xaml?eid=3709626441465918</wp:Param>" +
                   "</wp:Toast> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";
```

But if I try to send multiple params like this:

```
string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                   "<wp:Toast>" +
                        "<wp:Text1>" + TextBoxTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text1>" +
                        "<wp:Text2>" + TextBoxSubTitle.Text.ToString() + "</wp:Text2>" +
                        "<wp:Param>/Evento.xaml?eid=3709626441465918;lat=28.5146;lng=77.1972;EventName=aa</wp:Param>" +
                   "</wp:Toast> " +
                "</wp:Notification>";
```

On receiving end i get `eid` itself equal to

```
"3709626441465918;lat=28.5146;lng=77.1972;EventName=aa""3709626441465918;lat=28.5146;lng=77.1972;EventName=aa"
```

I tried "&" instead of ";" and toast notification won't even work.

Comment: You should try with `&amp;` instead of `&` or `;`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are misusing the semi-colon character in the URI.

A semi-colon is a reserved, sub-delimiter character and should be encoded (as %3B) when used as you are.

```
/Evento.xaml?eid=3709626441465918;lat=28.5146;lng=77.1972;EventName=aa
```

should be

```
/Evento.xaml?eid=3709626441465918%3Blat=28.5146%3Blng=77.1972%3BEventName=aa
```